# Expo how to subscribe to FCM Channels

Tags: push-notification, expo

> https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications/

Following the docs I couldn't find a way to subscribe to a topic on fcm. I don't know if APN has topics like fcm. But if it does, it would be great to be able to subscribe to channels on both Android and iOS. Now the question is does expo support this behavior? For both Android and iOS or any?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported on Expo, you need to manage things yourself and push a msg to each user using their token.

Comment: Yes you can,But an analogy could be like using sql to select all the records or select one by one in a for each loop.It is not the best analogy but you get the point.This feature should be implemented because your server or host is a lot weaker than servers that google uses.

Comment: If you want this feature right now you need to eject Expo and implement RN firebase module, its a real pain. https://rnfirebase.io/